# jquery remove generated label on validate success

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an optional password field and then a "type same password" field.  The user would only use this if they wanted to update their existing password, so validation is only supposed to fire if the fields are not blank.

I have a function called success that adds a label after the element with a CSS that gives it a green tick mark:

```
success: function (label) {
                label.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                        .closest('.form-element').addClass('success');
    },
```

I'm stuck figuring out how to remove that tick mark though if I have no value in the password confirmation field.

I created a function called ignoreifblank that removes the other validation errors and success messages, but I can't get it to remove the label with the green tick.

```
$('.ignoreifblank').blur(function(){
    if( $(this).val()=="") {
     $(this).parent().removeClass("success error");
    }
};
```

I've tried variations of $(this).next('.label').remove(); and $(this).next('.label').css('display','none'); but I don't seem to be selecting the generated label correctly.

Comment: Please can you show us your full code on jsfiddle

Comment: Where is the label added ?

Comment: I figured it out - had a bad typo in the code.  The code that works for me is:    $(this).next('label').css('display','none');

Answer (score 0):

Bad typo - this works for the next generated label:

```
$(this).next('label').css('display','none');
```

Thanks for the replies.